# Selecting descendants except first level one

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="has-child will-be-ignored">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="has-child will-be-selected">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li class="has-child will-be-selected">
            <ul>
              ...
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <ul>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Is there any way in CSS to select elements with class `has-child will-be-selected`. These elements could be continued any number of level.

UPDATE:

`will-be-ignored` and `will-be-selected` classes are just to highlight them to be selected. These classes don't actually exist.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: I think you can safely assume those classes don't actually exist :P

Comment: I misinterpreted - the `.has-child` class probably exists in the markup. Pretty sure the `will-be-*` classes are just there to highlight which elements *should* be selected though, otherwise it makes the question all too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, step to the first level and then target the ones underneath that:

```
ul > li.has-child li.has-child
```

Of course, depending on your structure, you may have to anchor that first-level `ul` to its own parent to make sure that its child `li` isn't inadvertently matching the selector, e.g. if your `ul` happens to be in *another* list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ul ul > li.has-child.will-be-selected
```

Comment: Sorry, `will-be-selected` classes are just to highlight them to be selected. My bad for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most straight-forward way would be this selector...

```
li.has-child.will-be-selected
```

that selects all elements that has both `has-child` class and `will-be-selected` class as per your question description. However, if you want to skip the first level use...

```
ul ul li.has-child.will-be-selected
```

as per the title of your question

Comment: Sorry, `will-be-selected` classes are just to highlight them to be selected. My bad for the question.